# Is it possible to filter the descendant elements returned from an XPath query?

Tags: xpath, yql, yahoo-api

At the moment, I'm trying to scrape forms from some sites using the following query:

```sql
select * from html 
where url="http://somedomain.com" 
and xpath="//form[@action]"
```

This returns a result like so:

```
{
    form: {
        action: "/some/submit",
        id: "someId",
        div: {
            input: [
               ... some input elements here
            ]
        }
        fieldset: {
            div: {
                input: [
                    ... some more input elements here
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On some sites this could go many levels deep, so I'm not sure how to begin trying to filter out the unwanted elements in the result.  If I could filter them out here, then it would make my back-end code much simpler.  Basically, I'd just like the form and any label, input, select (and option) and textarea descendants.

Here's an XPath query I tried, but I realised that the element hierarchy would not be maintained and this might cause a problem if there are multiple forms on the page:

```xpath
//form[@action]/descendant-or-self::*[self::form or self::input or self::select or self::textarea or self::label]
```

However, I did notice that the elements returned by this query were no longer returned under divs and other elements beneath the form.

Comment: How crucial is it the filtered nodes are returned under the `form` tag? I can't see what the result of your query looks like, but the elements should come back in the order they appear in the document. I can think of a way to filter what nodes you need, but not within the parent tag as you seem to want..

Comment: Also, are you using XPath 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: @JWiley: it's XPath 1.0, I don't think YQL supports 2.0.  It's very crucial that the filtered nodes are returned under the form tag, as there may be multiple forms on a single page, which would make it impossible to know which inputs belong to which form element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will be possible in a plain query as you have tried.

However, it would not be *too* much work to create a new data table containing some JavaScript that does the filtering you're looking for.

**Data table**

A quick, little `<execute>` block might look something like the following.

```
var elements = y.query("select * from html where url=@u and xpath=@x", {u: url, x: xpath}).results.elements();
var results = <url url={url}></url>;
for each (element in elements) {
    var result = element.copy();
    result.setChildren("");
    result.normalize();
    for each (descendant in y.xpath(element, filter)) {
        result.node += descendant;
    }
    results.node += result;
}
response.object = results;
```

» See [the full example data table](https://gist.github.com/salathe/5120512).

**Example query**

```
use "store://VNZVLxovxTLeqYRH6yQQtc" as example;
select * from example where url="http://www.yahoo.com"
```

» See [this query in the YQL console](http://y.ahoo.it/u/i+z)

**Example results**

[image: Query results XML]

Hopefully the above is a step in the right direction, and doesn't look too daunting.

**Links**

- [Open Data Tables Reference](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-reference.html)
- [Executing JavaScript in Open Data Tables](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-chapter.html)
- [YQL Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/editor/)

Comment: Thanks for this, it's a big help.  I'd not gotten around to investigating using JavaScript in Open Data Tables yet, but it looks like I might be able to do a lot of useful stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would filter specific nodes but still allow the parent tag with all attributes to show:

```
//form[@name]/@* | //form[@action]/descendant-or-self::node()[name()='input' or name()='select' or name()='textarea' or name()='label']
```

If there are multiple form tags on the page, they should be grouped off by this parent tag and not all wedged together and unidentifiable.

You could also reverse the union if it would help how you'd like the nodes to appear:

```
//form[@action]/descendant-or-self::node()[name()='input' or name()='select' or name()='textarea' or name()='label'] | //form[@name]/@*
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but, unfortunately, neither of these improve on my own attempt at a solution―the result remains the same.

Comment: The result should not be the same, your current xpath does not give a grouping with an included `form` tag as parent.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that yours doesn't either, copied and pasted straight into the query